# How to build a docker image in another directory?

Tags: docker, path, docker-image, docker-build

I have a root folder called `fold_01`, in this folder, I have two folders `folder_02` and `folder_03`,each folder contains a Dockerfile, I have a script in folder_03, in order to run this script, I have to build an image from the Dockerfile in the `folder_02`, how can I specify the path in the command?

I tried to add one line `docker build  . -t name` to the first line in the script that I want to run, but this line actually build the image using the info from `folder_03` not `folder_02`, how can I specify the directory?

```
folder_01
├── folder_02├──Dockerfile_02
├── folder_03├──Dockerfile_03
```

In the folder_03 dir, how can I use `docker build` to specify path for `Dockerfile_02` and build the image by using it??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify a `Dockerfile` by path with:

```
--file , -f     Name of the Dockerfile (Default is ‘PATH/Dockerfile’)
```

So the command will be:

```
docker run -t name -f folder_02/Dockerfile .
```

Reference:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Comment: do you mean add both those two lines in the script I want to run? And the second one should be ```docker build``` not ```docker run```

Comment: think again, make sure you go through this document https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/, try to get answer by yourself.